# Email View doesn't show interpreted HTML

Tags: android

I want compile an email with HTML content which users can see before send it.

I use an

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
```

But I cannot see an HTML interpreted, see the image below:
[image]

[image]

There is a way to show an HTML interpreted email content?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to set type for intent :see this method:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setType%28java.lang.String%29

---

you ahve to add also this line for it shows like html for ur data:

---

```
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));**strong text**
```

Comment: Its not working. Please see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718952/html-display-in-email-body-android